# Separate service from controller in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I would like to separate the service from the controller in my angularjs application, I did it in a following way:

the `app.js` there is:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['restangular','ui.router','myApp.controllers','myApp.services']);
```

the `controllers.js`:

```
 angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]);
```

the `services.js`:

```
angular.module('myApp.services',[]);
```

I have a controllers related to the `controllers.js`:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]).controller('ContactController', ContactController);

ContactController.$inject = [ '$scope', 'ContactService' ];
function ContactController($scope, ContactService) {
     console.log("here call ctrl contact");
     $scope.contacts = ContactService.getAll(); 
}
```

This `ContactController` call the service `ContactService` defined in a separate file:
ContactService .js

```
angular.module('myApp.services',[])

.factory('ContactService', function(Restangular){
    var Contacts = Restangular.all('contacts');

    return {
        getAll : function(){
            return Contacts.getList().$object;
        }
    };

});
```

the problem is when I have tried to invoke this controller I got the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ContactServiceProvider <-
>   ContactService
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/unpr?p0=ContactServiceProvider%20%3C-%20ContactService

how can I fix that?

UPDATE:
this is the structure of my app:

[image: structure of the app]

I have in app.js:

```
.state('contacts', {
        url: '/contacts',
        templateUrl: 'templates/contacts.html',
        controller: 'ContactController'
    })  
    .state('todos', {
        url: '/todos',
        templateUrl: 'templates/todos.html',
        controller: 'TodoController'
    })
```

in the index.html i imported all th js files:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have initialized a module withm, `angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])` again **you should not use second parameter dependency([])**

So,
in your controller,

```
 `angular.module('myApp.controllers',[])` should be `angular.module('myApp.controllers')`
```

So,

```
angular
  .module('myApp.controllers')
  .controller('ContactController', ContactController);
ContactController.$inject = ['$scope', 'ContactService'];
function ContactController($scope, ContactService) {
  console.log('here call ctrl contact');
  $scope.contacts = ContactService.getAll();
}
```

The same applies to your **service/factory**,

```
angular.module('myApp.services')
.factory('ContactService', function(Restangular){
    var Contacts = Restangular.all('contacts');

    return {
        getAll : function(){
            return Contacts.getList().$object;
        }
    };

});
```

PS: After seeing the order of your js file injection in `index.html` I found the major issue.

The order of your file scripts is wrong. In `ContactController` you are using `contactService` which is not defined before it.
So change the scripts order in `index.html` as below.

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/ContactService.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/TodoService.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ContactController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/TodoController.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried to move the second part dependency [], and i got the same error. Maybe i have missed somthing

Comment: move means? you removed the second parameter?

Comment: also make sure that `ContactService.js` is added in `index.html`

Comment: please can you have another look in my question , i updated it

Comment: @selma, heyy.. I was editing the same... Just took time to type all the scripts by myself. So was late in updating the answer. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to include

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers',['myApp.services'])
```

instead of

```
 angular.module('myApp.controllers',[])
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue fixed by reorder the import of my js files as follows:

the app.js then the file services and then the controllers.

[image: import js files]

Comment: heyy.. I was editing the same... Just took time to type all the scripts by myself. So was late in updating the answer. Updated my answer.